# Let $S$ and $W$ be subsets of a vector space $V$. Show that if $S$ is a subset of $W$, then $\mathrm{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{span}(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

Let $S$ and $W$ be subsets of a vector space $V$. Show that if $S$ is a subset of $W$, then $\mathrm{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{span}(W)$.

Ok I'm finally understanding what each of these things mean.. but I'm running out of ideas on how to actually show it without using arbitrary vector space examples like Rn. Since sets and subspaces are kind of new its hard to figure out how to write correct proofs with them.

I can see how if $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $S = \{(1,1,1)\}$ and $W = \{(1,1,1), (1,1,2)\}$ then $\mathrm{span}(S) = R1(line), span(W) = R2(plane)$ and that R1 is a subspace of R2... im just having trouble showing this officially when all vector spaces and sets are completely in general....

I could get as far as writing out $S=(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n)$, $u_i \in V$ and same with $W$, but I can't really figure out what else to do in this sort of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we know the span of a set of vectors is, by definition, the set of all finite linear combinations.  So, if we have a set $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots, v_{n} \}$, then:

span$\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots, v_{n} \} = \{c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2} + \dots + c_{n}v_{n} \mid c_{i} \in \mathbb{R} \}$ (all possible linear combinations where the coefficients are real numbers).

**Note:** In my example set above, I only have finitely many elements.  But there is no reason to believe that when we discuss the span of a set, the underlying set is finite.  It could be infinite.  But the span, by definition, consists of all possible *finite* linear combinations of elements in our underlying set.  So you only have finite combinations -- no infinite sums.

Ok, so then if $S$, a set, is a subset of $W$, another set, then every element of $S$ is in $W$, right?  So that means any linear combination of elements of $S$ is also a linear combination of elements of $W$ since elements of $S$ are elements of $W$.  Then that means all possible linear combinations of elements of $S$ are linear combinations of elements of $W$.  So, that means the span of $S$ is contained in the span of $W$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @OC-Sansoo I added a note.  But I don't see why the argument should be any different.  If it is, can you clarify?

Comment: @OC-Sansoo I agree with you.  Why is this noteworthy?  In other words, how does this go against my argument?  It still follows that if $S$ is a subset of $W$, then the span of $S$ is a subset of the span of $W$.

Comment: yeah, this makes sense. I guess i should write out the span of S, the span of W, and write that each element of span(S) E span(W), and somehow summarize this means span(S) is a subset of span(W). I was thinking of re-writing the set W as {u1,u2,..un,w1,w2,..2n} then writing out the span of that, but I guess using words to explain it is enough. Would summarizing the last part the way you did be sufficient?

Comment: @JL Well, the problem is that you don't know that $W$ has only finitely many elements.  I think you should use words.  Now that you understand the idea, take out a blank piece of paper, and explain the idea in your own words, as if you were teaching it to someone else.  That's what you should turn in (if this is homework).  Proofs are always personal -- you explain things the way you understand them.

Comment: @OC-Sansoo Why does my argument make these assumptions?  I gave a specific example where the underlying set has finitely many vectors, but my argument really begins in the last paragraph, and there I didn't assume anything about the cardinality of the underlying sets.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot that's what I normally would have done all along, but then one day.... I did exactly that on a test. I explained the whole proof in complete details using words referencing theorems. And then the teacher went and told me "I didn't do any work." and gave it a 0. =| ever since i felt like there was nothing I could do to guarantee my answers were good enough...

Comment: question: would it be totally wrong to write if S is a subset of W, then S = {s1,s2,...sn,w1,w2,...wn) and then write the span of that with k's and +'s thrown in then show that span(S) is a subspace of span(W) by showing the elements of  span(S) are in span(W) ?

Comment: Sometimes proofs require that you write things like "Let $W = \{w_{1}, w_{2}, \dots, w_{n} \}$", for example if you know the underlying set is finite.  But words always help to explain each step and show that you understand what is going on.  The best I can offer is that, after you write your proof, ask your teacher to look it over before you officially turn it in (if this is homework).  He or she should be able to help you hone your skills further.

Comment: @JL Again, you can't be sure that $S$ is a finite set, so you don't know if it has the form $\{ s_{1}, s_{2}, \dots, s_{n} \}$, for example.  It could be infinite.

Comment: if I can't be sure.. then could I just end each set with .... or write s(sub infinity sign) as the last element?

Comment: @JL Definitely not! Here's why: Suppose you could do that, say, write $S = \{ s_{n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$.  Then you are saying $S$ is countably infinite.  But $S$ could be uncountably infinite.  So trying to list the elements of $S$ is not a good idea since you know very little about the set $S$.  If you want a slightly more formal proof, here it is: Let $S \subseteq W$.  Then for each $s \in S$, $s \in W$.  But then we know span{$S$} $= \{c_{1}v_{1} + \dots + c_{n}v_{n} \mid c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, v_{i} \in S \}$.  Since $S \subseteq W$, every element of the form...

Comment: $c_{1}v_{1} + \dots + c_{n}v_{n}$ is in span{$W$}, since this set is precisely $\{c_{1}w_{1} + \dots + c_{m}w_{m} \mid c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, w_{i} \in W \}$.  So, each element in span{$S$} is in span{$W$}, which shows span{$S$} $\subseteq$ span{$W$}.

Comment: when you say every element of the form ....., do you mean every individual civi as an element or the whole sum as an element? And also, are you saying span of a set is also a set? I thought the span was always a vector space. but I guess a vector space is the set of the entire space. also the last part of the proof question says "subspace". can that subset symbol also be used as a subspace symbol?

Comment: @JL I mean the whole sum is itself an arbitrary element in the span.  And you are right, the span is a vector space, and it is also a set.  A vector space is just a set of things, but we also define two operations on this set: addition and scalar multiplication.  Finally, as for the subspace part: $L$ is a subspace of $K$ if $L$ is itself a vector space, and it is contained in the vector space $K$.  Well, we know span{$S$} is a vector space, and so is span{$W$}.  We proved span{$S$} is a subset of span{$W$}, which means span{$S$} is a *subspace* of span{$W$}.

Comment: ok, so you are adding that to the end of the proof, which at first you concluded with span(S) is a subset of span(W).

Comment: @JL Yes, you are right.  Since I have seen this material many times before, I didn't feel the need to add the detail about the subspace.  But I should have realized that it is absolutely important for someone at your level.  Good job for keeping an eye on details.  It shows you are really making an effort to understand this material. Your proof should definitely include why being a subset implies it is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but did you mean to say "subspace" instead of subset? If so, vector spaces are closed with respect to scalar multiplication and addition; therefore, $\mathrm{span}(S)$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$, which is a subspace of $W$ (i.e. $\mathrm{span}(S)$ consists of linear combinations of elements of $W$, which lie in $W$). Now show that $\mathrm{span}(S)$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication and addition.

Also, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not an arbitrary vector space. It is actually a specific one (or a family of vector spaces). In your question, $V$ would be the arbitrary vector space. But it is still good to build intuition with examples as you have.

Comment: This question is exactly how it was shown in my homework packet. (not sure if teacher possibly made a typo.) If it is the way it is written, does that make your first paragraph not apply?

Comment: No, I made a mistake. The way it is written is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ form a vector space over the field $F$

For any set $S \subseteq V$, $span(S)$ always forms a subspace of $V$.(check).Let $w\in span(S)$ then $w=c_1s_1+c_2s_2+......+c_ns_n$ where $c_i\in F $  and $s_i \in S$.Since $S\subseteq W$ so $s_i \in W$ and hence $w \in span(W)$.

Comment: is that first symbol you wrote mean subset? because I was told subset is like that without the line under it. I'm also not sure how to write a symbol for subspace.